# Why imageboard scripts do not use database?

Tags: php, database, filesystems

I was very surprised when downloaded two imageboard php scripts. There is no connection to database, threads and posts are listed as files and folders. Is this way faster than standard mysql database connection or there is another reason?

Comment: You downloaded 2 random scripts from the internet and assume that 'most imageboard scripts do not use a database'?

Comment: there are only few imageboard scripts in internet

Comment: Unless few means '3', that still isn't a good argument.

Comment: I found 5, downloaded 2.
Changed topic to be more concrete. Daniel don't be so negative;)

Comment: Did you end using a database-less PHP imageboard? Can you share what you choose? experiences? lessons learned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two factors lead to this. 1) The number one purpose of imageboards is to hold images, and images don't do well when stored in a database. 2) Threads in an imageboard are strictly linear, therefore a simple monotonic filename scheme suffices to distinguish them.

Comment: so seeking file in filesystem is faster than select from database?

Comment: It can be. Or it could be slower. It's a different *kind* of access.